# ImageMap with lists in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I'm developing a custom webpart for SharePoint 2007 using C# and Visual Studio. I need to create an ImageMap (a picture with links on certain portions of it), but instead of taking you to the linked webpage when clicking the hotspot, I need to display a list.

I have done the ImageMap, for example, on an image of the planet when you click the African continent it takes you to www.africa.com. What I need is, when you click the African continent part of the picture, to display a (dropdown) list.

This is useful for showing different data in lisst based on the hotspot clicked on the image.

Can someone give me an idea how can I do this? Or maybe there is another mechanism which helps me achieve this?

Comment: Just a hint.. that's probably not an imagemap anymore.  You'll need to look at the mousedown JavaScript event.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Any help o how to do this would be appeciated. So baiscally I have to insert client side scripting into a webpart... no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do this using jQuery + Javascript.

Basically I created an HTML ImageMap and on every region I added a listener on the mouseover, mouseout, click events. In the handlers, the Javascript code worked perfectly.

I embedded the page with the ImageMap in an iFrame into the SharePoint webpart that I needed.